# Play a (short) sound extremely frequently?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I want to create a metronome using `setInterval`. I want to be able to reach high bpms like 300 bpm. Even if the file is short enough to be played as many times as it's needed, it will hiccup *very* easily. Furthermore, many browsers have issues with short audio files - Safari for MP3 and Firefox for WAV.
I tried using multiple files as you see below, to no avail.

```
    metronome = setInterval(function () {
        if (!tick.played) {
            tick.play();
        } else {
            tick2.play();
        }
    }, 200); // = 300 bmp
```

1. How can I play a short audio file very frequently?
2. What's the best file extension to do so?

Comment: I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Family/o5juz57p/ It uses a method to increase the timer accuracy from here: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/ and plays an embedded wav file, which may help. It still doesn't seem to be very accurate though, so I didn't want to put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Web Audio API for accurate timing, JavaScript's setTimeout can have up to a 10ms offset. There's a metronome demo using [`audioContext.currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/currentTime) at it's core. See this [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/) for details on audio scheduling. See this [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VjNllxXe7wp22gLPnlgt?p=info) for Web Audio Metronome demo.